# How to set optuna's study.optimize verbosity to 0?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, optuna

I want to set optuna's study.optimize verbosity to 0. I thought `optuna.logging.set_verbosity(0)` might do it, but I still get the `Trial 0 finished with value ....` updates for every trial

What is the correct way to do this? Unfortunately, extensive searching through the docs still only results in the above method.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `optuna.logging.set_verbosity(optuna.logging.ERROR)`?

Comment: @FlaviaGiammarino I haven't, I'll try that, what will that do? change trial updates to just printing error messages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
optuna.logging.set_verbosity(optuna.logging.WARNING)
```

It basically changes the level of verbosity.

For more level choices, check optuna's official guides [here](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/logging.html).

Answer (score 2):

`optuna` warnings tend to be raised using standard pythonic `warnings.warn()` (which explains why `optuna.logging.set_verbosity()` does not always work to suppress them), so you can silence them all at once with:

```
# treat all python warnings as lower-level "ignore" events
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Be aware however, that this will silence also the useful and infrequent ones like deprecation warnings.